# Unique bar codes assigned to a machine and then storing attributes in Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

My company wants me to try and incorporate a free bar code scanner into the VB.NET Visual Studio database that I am currently building.  The hope is that we can take a stack of sticker bar codes into a facility, take a picture of the bar code, place the sticker onto a machine, and fill out an attribute form.  The bar code sticker would then serve as an easy way to reference the data in the database from tablets via picture.

I have done some research on this and cannot find much about assigning printed bar codes.  Does anyone have any advice?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this a long time ago with a Zebra printer and iTextSharp:

https://github.com/kusl/itextsharp/blob/master/tags/iTextSharp_5_4_5/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/Barcode.cs

https://github.com/kusl/itextsharp/blob/master/tags/iTextSharp_5_4_5/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/BarcodeQRCode.cs

I don't have access to the code anymore but what I did was to render the barcode inside a bitmap control from a given string, then get the bytes and store them on a SQL Server table in a `binary` datatype field. Then I could query it from the application, from Crystal Reports or SQL Server Reporting Services.

For uniqueness, you could generate a GUID.